# How to prevent scroll effect from making my screen flicker on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

using chrome and ff so far have made a nasty glitch when using scrollTo function?  anyone know how to prevent this from happening?
**[Live Code](http://designobvio.us/para/)**

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="listItem"><img src="asset/img/logo.png" ></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a onclick="scrollTo('#container',500);" href="#">Company</a><span> / </span></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a onclick="scrollTo('.flexslider-container',500);" href="#">Service</a><span> / </span></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a onclick="scrollTo('#map',500);" href="#">Map</a><span> / </span></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a onclick="scrollTo('#footer',500);" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <p>250-610-9100</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollTo(o, s) {
    var d = $(o).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
        scrollTop: d
    }, s);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be attaching events via `.on()`, not shoving code into the `onclick` attribute.

The (more) proper solution is to give you links a `class`:

```
<a href="..." class="menu-link">...</a>
```

And then some fancy `data` attributes:

```
<a href="..." class="menu-link" data-target="#container" data-duration="500">...</a>
```

And in your code, add this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // <---- This is the magic stuff

    scrollTo($(this).data('target'), $(this).data('duration'));
  });
});
```

Basically, you give your elements special attributes that can be read with jQuery's `.data()` function. Then, instead of adding a function call to each link, you attach one magic function to *all* of them.

---

If you want to keep your current code (ehh), just add `return false;` at the end of every `onclick` attribute:

```
<a onclick="scrollTo('.flexslider-container',300);return false;" href="#">Service</a>
```

This prevents the default action from occurring (scrolling to the top of the page).

I recommend my first solution. You aren't doing jQuery any justice if you are only using it to a third of its potential.

Comment: hey man I want to make your solution work!  It opens up a lot of doors while i'm trying to learn jquery.  Unfortunately, it's not working.  There were a few semantic errors that i fixed yet it still didnt work. could you get me a jsfiddles?

Comment: Try it now. I forgot a `);` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stop()` to clear the animation queue

```
function scrollTo(o, s) {
        var d = $(o).offset().top;
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: d
        }, s);
    }
```

As talking about anchors you should prevent the default anchor behavior using `preventDefault()`:

```
$('.wrapper a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```