# Getting rid of the flicker when scrolling to anchor in jquery

Tags: jquery

Jquery does what is suppose to but I can't get rid of the **flicker** when I click the anchor links.

The `return false;` seems to be doing the trick in `go-to-top`. Also, I want to keep the `#pageurl` if I want to come back to a previous page for mobile purposes.

```
$("a.jump-to-link").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 
      $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top -50 }, 500);
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

This is my [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/labanino/pen/KoeMdO?editors=1010) if you want to check the code.

Comment: I cannot notice the flicker, works smooth here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent scroll effect from making my screen flicker on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027233/how-to-prevent-scroll-effect-from-making-my-screen-flicker-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe changing window hash does something, so probably you can put window hash changing into callback function of scroll.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 
      $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top -50 }, 500, function() {
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
}
);
```